Getting "tensorflow.python module not found", when I try to import tensorflow after setting up cuda and cudnn on python 3.9, windows 11, RTX 3060
So, I was setting up CUDA on my laptop running windows11 with RTX 3060. I am running CUDA Toolkit 12.3 with cuDNN 8.9.7 on Python 3.9. Tensorflow was running fine prior to setting up CUDA.
After everything was properly set-up, I tried running it on PyTorch and it worked.
However, since then, if I import tensorflow, I get the error "tensorflow.python module not found."
Everytime I ran to import tensorflow
import tensorflow as tf

I get the following error message:
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1], line 1
----> 1 import tensorflow as tf

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py:37
     34 import sys as _sys
     35 import typing as _typing
---> 37 from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
     38 from tensorflow.python.util.lazy_loader import LazyLoader as _LazyLoader
     40 # Make sure code inside the TensorFlow codebase can use tf2.enabled() at import.

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.python'

Anyone HELP???

I have gone down to the file path (C:\Users\iamsh\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\tensorflow) and checked, but there is no python folder being created.
I changed the versions of the CUDA toolkit, cuDNN and tensorflow and tried different combinations. None have worked so far.
I have also tried it in a clean conda environment but to no avail.
